# Constraint in a 2d pixel matrix

Tags: system-verilog

Let's assume there's a 2d pixel matrix 1920 x 1080 in size. I want to constrain the matrix such that in the neighborhood of an off pixel(0) there are only ON pixels(1-255). The pattern should be something like this, for a smaller 5x4 matrix:

```
x x x x 
x 0 x 0
x x x x
x 0 x 0
x x x x
```

What would be a better way to solve this constraint, assuming I don't use the foreach loop something as described below:

```
foreach(mat[i][j]){
  mat[i][i] = 0;
}
foreach(mat[i][j]){
  if(mat[i][j] == 0) begin
     mat[i-1][j] = $urandom_range(1,255);
     mat[i][j-1] = $urandom_range(1,255);
     mat[i-1][j-1] = $urandom_range(1,255);
     ..etc
  end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to do constrained randomization you can't use `$urandom(...)`. You need to use classes and the `randomize()` function.

Put the pixels in a `matrix` class:

```
class matrix;

  parameter WIDTH = 10;
  parameter HEIGHT = 5;

  rand bit pixels[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

  // ...

endclass
```

I used `bit` instead of `bit [7:0]`, because we want to randomize whether a pixel is on or off. It's possible to use `bit [7:0]`, but pixels in the off state are very unlikely. More on this later.

We model the constraints that state that next to an off pixel all others are on:

```
class matrix;

  // ...

  constraint on_next_to_off {
    foreach (pixels[i,j]) {
      if (pixels[i][j] == 0) {
        pixels[i-1][j-1] != 0;
        pixels[i-1][j] != 0;
        pixels[i-1][j+1] != 0;

        pixels[i][j-1] != 0;
        pixels[i][j+1] != 0;

        pixels[i+1][j-1] != 0;
        pixels[i+1][j] != 0;
        pixels[i+1][j+1] != 0;
      }
    }
  }
endclass
```

We can try to run this, but it will fail. This is because we didn't handle the edge cases. If the pixel is on the topmost line, then there are no pixels further above to constraint, so the constrains that reference `i-1` do not make sense and need to exclude this case. The same applies for the bottom-most line and for the leftmost and rightmost columns. We have to add guards for all of these cases:

```
class matrix;

  // ...

  constraint on_next_to_off {
    foreach (pixels[i,j]) {
      if (pixels[i][j] == 0) {
        if (i > 1) {
          if (j > 1)
            pixels[i-1][j-1] != 0;
          pixels[i-1][j] != 0;
          if (j < WIDTH-1)
            pixels[i-1][j+1] != 0;
        }

        if (j > 1)
          pixels[i][j-1] != 0;
        if (j < WIDTH-1)
          pixels[i][j+1] != 0;

        if (i < HEIGHT-1) {
          if (j > 1)
            pixels[i+1][j-1] != 0;
          pixels[i+1][j] != 0;
          if (j < WIDTH-1)
            pixels[i+1][j+1] != 0;
        }
      }
    }
  }
endclass
```

To debug this we can add a `print()` function to `matrix`:

```
class matrix;

  // ...

  function void print();
    foreach (pixels[i]) begin
      string line;
      foreach (pixels[,j])
        line = $sformatf("%s %d", line, pixels[i][j]);
      $display(line);
    end
  endfunction

endclass
```

We can try this out with the following code:

```
module test;

  initial begin
    matrix m = new();
    if (!m.randomize())
      $fatal(0, "randerr");
    m.print();
  end

endmodule
```

If you want to use `bit [7:0]` instead of `bit`, the constraints will still work. As I mentioned above, it will be very unlikely that the solver chooses `0` as a value for a pixel, though, because it has 255 other possibilities to choose from. To make this more likely you can add an extra constraint that states that pixels are either on or off with equal probability:

```
class matrix;

  // ...

  constraint on_or_off_equal {
    foreach (pixels[i,j]) {
      pixels[i][j] == 0 dist {
        0 := 1,
        1 := 1
      };
    }
  }

endclass
```